# Is the following theorem on certain dense subgraphs optimal?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

In my introductory course on graph theory the following statement was proven.

> Any finite graph $G$ with at least one edge contains an induced subgraph $H$ such that $d(H) \geq d(G)$ and $2\cdot \delta(H) > d(H)$.

Does there exist a $1<c<2$ such that the above theorem still holds if we replace the expression $2\cdot \delta(H) > d(H)$ by $c\cdot \delta(H) > d(H)$? Do you have a counterexample for any given $c$?

Looking at the proofs of the theorem did not help.
One proof goes as follows: Consider induced subgraphs $H$ of $G$ with $d(H)$ maximal. Let $H$ be one of those graphs with $|H|$ minimal. The proof then goes on to show that $H$ fulfils the properties required. Note that we did not chose $H$ to be "one of those graphs with $\delta(H)$ maximal.”

The other proof known to me I would consider essentially the same. It gives an algorithm to construct $H$ by deleting a vertex that has relatively low degree in the graph at hand in each step. Here, I am not sure that the algorithm cannot be optimised. Maybe one should not delete an arbitrary vertex with relatively low degree in the graph at hand, but one should specify (if two or more exist) which one to delete. Thereby, one could "improve” the inequality maybe. Alternatively, by considering graphs where in each step of the algorithm there is only one choice of vertex we might be able to construct a counterexample for any $c$.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple example, any tree on $n$ vertices has average degree $2 - \frac2n$, which is almost $2$, but all of its subgraphs have minimum degree at most $1$.

More generally, consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{n, kn}$. With $(k+1)n$ vertices and $kn^2$ edges, its average degree is $\frac{2kn^2}{(k+1)n} = (2 - \frac{2}{k+1})n$, which we can make arbitrarily close to $2n$ by increasing $k$.

However, there is no subgraph of $K_{n,kn}$ with minimum degree larger than $n$. If we keep at least one vertex on the side which originally had $kn$ vertices, that vertex has degree at most $n$; if we remove all vertices on that side, then all vertices on the other side are left with degree $0$.

So your theorem cannot be improved to $c \cdot \delta(H) > d(H)$ for any $c < 2$.

Comment: Thank you, at least the tree-example I should have come up with.